# Haskell multiply index

Tags: haskell

If I wanted to returns a list whose elements are
equal to the corresponding element of the input list multiplied by its location in the list, I could do something like the following:

```
ML :: [Int] -> [Int]
ML [] = []
ML (x:xs) =  x * x-1 : ML xs
```

But the corresponding list I got when I entered `[6,3,5,1]` gives the result of `[35,8,24,0]`
Is there a similar way I could get `[0,3,10,3]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code, as written (assuming the function name is actually a valid function name like `ml`) was parsed as:

```
ml :: [Int] -> [Int]
ml [] = []
ml (x:xs) = ((x * x)-1) : (ml xs)
```

This is because `(*)` has higher fixity(precedence) than `(+)`, which again has higher fixity than `(:)`, and function application `ml xs` has the highest fixity.
That is you are changing each element to its square, and subtracting 1.

Now what you actually want is some way to know the index of the element.
This can be achieved by using an extra argument in the recursion.

```
ml :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
ml _ [] = []
ml i (x:xs) = x*i : ml (i+1) xs
```

But then notice that our function's signature changed, we are now accepting an extra `Int` parameter, and we are expecting the user to call as with `ml 0 someList`, but we don't want to rely on the user passing valid data, and we want the user to just pass the list. So we can rename this function to some other name, say `ml_internal` and have `ml` be the correct code

```
ml :: [Int] -> [Int]
ml xs = ml_internal 0 xs

ml_internal :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
ml_internal _ [] = []
ml_internal i (x:xs) = x*i : ml_internal (i+1) xs
```

Now we don't want to expose `ml_internal`, we could do this by putting this code in a module and only exporting `ml`, but there's no reason to do that. We also might not want `ml_internal` to be available to other functions in the same module. So what we can do is put `ml_internal` in a `where` clause for `ml`:

```
ml :: [Int] -> [Int]
ml xs = ml_internal 0 xs
  where
    ml_internal :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
    ml_internal _ [] = []
    ml_internal i (x:xs) = x*i : ml_internal (i+1) xs
```

Now we can also omit `ml_internal`'s type signature, since it can be inferred, and in some cases the compiler can't handle the explicit signature correctly without a language extension called `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled.
We can also rename `ml_internal` to `go`, which is a widely used name for such constructs, to get to the following code for `ml`:

```
ml :: [Int] -> [Int]
ml xs = go 0 xs
  where
    go _ [] = []
    go i (x:xs) = x*i : go (i+1) xs
```

Comment: @stephan The result *does* start with 0. `ml [6,5,3,1]` results in `[0,3,10,3]` (with the last definition I've given). This fits exactly the result you've wanted for this input. otherwise I'm not sure what you mean by "start from 0".

Comment: got it !! I really appriated

Comment: While this answer certainly works, it does not use the advantages functional languages have over imperative / iterative languages (on the contrary, it practically shows of the disadvantages). To see more haskellian approaches, I recommend the answers by [Igor Drozdov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52051643/2415161) and [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052427/2415161).

Comment: About some terminology: in the Haskell Report, “fixity” refers to *associativity* (left, right, none), although the *precedence* is part of a “fixity declaration”. Elsewhere, “fixity” usually refers to where an operator appears relative to its operands—prefix, infix, postfix, mixfix, distfix, circumfix…—but Haskell only has infix operators. Postfix is *sort of* supported with the `PostfixOperators` language pragma, but parentheses are always required because it works by desugaring the operator section `(x ◇)` into `(◇) x` instead of `\y -> x ◇ y` for some expression `x` and operator `◇`.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, [zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) function can help with it:

```
zipWith (*) [0..] [6, 3, 5, 1]
```

returns `[0, 3, 10, 3]`

The current code doesn't work, because it just calls `x * x - 1` on the current element, but [zipWith](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) is a function, which zips your list with a list of indexes (`zip [0..] [6, 3, 5, 1]` equals `[(0, 6), (1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 1)]`) and then evaluates the passed function, which takes 2 arguments on every element. It's something similar to:

```
map (uncurry (*)) $ zip [0..] [6, 3, 5, 1]
```

Thus, the function definition is:

```
ml :: Num c => [c] -> [c]
ml = zipWith (*) [0..]
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to look at indexes at all to solve this problem! Try this implementation:

```
ml :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
ml [] = []
ml (_:xs) = 0 : zipWith (+) xs (ml xs)
```

Rather than multiplying the nth element by n directly, we instead arrange to add together n copies of the nth element, one at a time. Surely slower than the iterative approach with explicit multiplication, but I think rather instructive for how it avoids mentioning indexes even once.

In real code, I would just use the `zipWith (*)` implementation proposed in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ML :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
ML [] _ = []
ML (x:xs) n = x * n : ML xs n+1
```

try this one instead. Pass the index of the elements as another parameter :)